# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int' ? How do i fix this?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the user to input 2 variables, iFirst and iSecond, if the first is bigger then the second, then display message. If iSecond is equal to iFirst display message, but if iSecond is bigger than iFirst, display iThird. No matter what i try it keeps coming up with this error at the end part of the code :(

any suggestions?

```
double int dFirst;
int iSecond;
int iThird;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a number betwen 1 and 10: ");
dFirst = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter another number between 1 and 10: ");
iSecond = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (dFirst > iSecond)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The first number is bigger than the second one you entered.");
}
else if (iSecond >= dFirst)
{
    Console.WriteLine("These numbers are equal");
}
else (iSecond >= dFirst)
{
    iThird = dFirst <= iSecond;
    Console.WriteLine("The number is: " + iThird);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: 3 Problems: A. What is `double int dFirst;`? Should be a `double` or an `int` but can't be both. B. Also an `else` can't a condition: `else (iSecond >= dFirst)`. Should be `else if` or no condition. C. And for the part of the question: `iThird = dFirst <= iSecond;` - You declared `iThird` as an `int` but the result of a `<=` is a `bool`

Comment: The main problem is the smile, secondary also `<= iSecond` doesn't have sense

Comment: Besides my comment above - also you will never reach the `else` - the conditions before check if `first > second` or `second >= first` - what other option is there for an else?..

Comment: "iSecond >= dFirst" is also wrong because he claims that this condition means that iSecond and dFirst are equal, which isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 1):

The error means exactly what it says - you're trying to assign a boolean value to an integer, which doesn't make sense. What's the integer value of `true`? That's like asking "what variety of apple is this orange?" However, you have other bugs as well - see my comments below.

```
double int dFirst;
```

There's no such thing as "double int." A double is a real number and an int is an integer, and obviously a number can't be both an integer and a real number.

```
    int iSecond;
    int iThird;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
    dFirst = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

This'll cause the program to crash if they enter something that's not a number. It also doesn't check to make sure that the user entered something between 1 and 10. Try something like the following:

```
        int intResult;
        // Prompt the user for an input until they enter a number between 1 - 10
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intResult) || intResult < 1 || intResult > 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid int - try again");
        }
```

The following code has the same exact problem:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter another number between 1 and 10: ");
    iSecond = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (dFirst > iSecond)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The first number is bigger than the second one you entered.");
    }
    else if (iSecond >= dFirst)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("These numbers are equal");
```

No, not necessarily - iSecond could be greater than dFirst. I assume you meant `==` here.

```
    }
    else (iSecond >= dFirst)
```

This should either be "else if" or simply "else." In this case, you can just do "else" - if first isn't greater than second and they're not equal, then obviously second has to be larger. Also, this condition is exactly the same as the previous condition, so there's absolutely no way that this condition can ever be met. Consider the following:

```
if (someCondition) {
   // ...
 }
// The following condition quite literally means "if not someCondition and someCondition," so obviously this couldn't possibly run.
else if (someCondition) { 
    // ...
 }
```

Recall that "else if" means "if the previous conditions are false **and** the conditions I specify here are true."

```
            {
        iThird = dFirst <= iSecond;
```

This is what's causing the error. I assume you meant something kind of like:

```
iThird = dFirst <= iSecond ? iSecond : dFirst;
```

This will assign the larger number to iThird, but you can make it whatever you want.

```
        Console.WriteLine("The number is: " + iThird);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
iThird = dFirst <= iSecond;
```

The `<=` operator results in a boolean (true or false). Try this instead:

```
iThird = dFirst <= iSecond ? (number if dFirst is less than or equal to iSecond) : (number if dFirst is greater than iSecond);
```

Comment: *One of* his problems is there :)

Comment: @EJoshuaS I meant the problem that the question refers to. The error message, specifically.

Comment: Fair enough, that is the one he asked about... just pointing out that there are other problems in the code too so the OP doesn't think that fixing that will automatically make the program work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 else (iSecond >= dFirst)
            {
        iThird = dFirst <= iSecond;


    }
```

this is your error. `dFirst <= iSecond` is returning a bool value which cannot be converted to an `int - iThird`. What you need to do is add or subtract the two numbers

```
   else (iSecond >= dFirst)
            {
        iThird = dFirst + iSecond;


    }
```

EDIT: there are many other errors in this code

```
    int dFirst;
    int iSecond;
    int iThird;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number betwen 1 and 10: ");
    dFirst = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter another number between 1 and 10: ");
    iSecond = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (dFirst > iSecond)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The first number is bigger than the second one you entered.");
    }
    else if (iSecond >= dFirst)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("These numbers are equal");
    }
    else if(iSecond >= dFirst)
            {
        iThird = dFirst <= iSecond; //this is the line from the question
        Console.WriteLine("The number is: " + iThird);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: This still won't compile

Comment: this is the answer to the question. Am I supposed to fix the whole code in an answer?

Comment: @M B - I am not saying what you are supposed to do :) I'm just saying that this code sample is still invalid and a "usful" answer is one that works.. I'm not from the quick downvoters but some people are

Comment: @MB What @GiladGreen is saying is that you can't add an `int` and a `double` and assign the resulting `double` to an `int` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with

```
 iThird = dFirst <= iSecond;
```

what exactly you want to do here. you have checked first number is greater or not , both are equal or not and do you want to check second number is equal or not?
Can you specify what your idea behind writing the second else if stmt